# Jasper - Detail band starting on page 2 when 1 large data set

Tags: jasper-reports

I am sending in data via the adapter in XML format.  When I send a large data set that surpasses the space on the first page (dozens of lines of data), Jasper starts the printing on page 2 and then 3, and so on.  I am simply looking to have the printing begin on page 1 and then continue to page 2.

I have tried adjusting Split Types, Sizing of the Detail Band, and adjusting the Detail Bands properties - but I must be missing something from very basic.

Github Location To The File
https://github.com/johnedoconnor/Jasper/blob/1db1be0761cea9675494fcdfbe1ca0baaf696c77/Jasper%20Page%20Issue

Comment: You have `splitType="Prevent"` set for the detail band.  Try changing it to `Stretch` or `Immediate`.

Comment: @dada67 - Yeah - I had attempted that first - Also retried that just now - No luck :-(